# Convert list of dictionaries containing another list of dictionaries to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I tried to look for the solution and I am unable to get 1. I have the following output from an api in python.

```
insights = [ <Insights> {
    "account_id": "1234",
    "actions": [
        {
            "action_type": "add_to_cart",
            "value": "8"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "purchase",
            "value": "2"
        }
    ],
    "cust_id": "xyz123",
    "cust_name": "xyz",
}, <Insights> {
    "account_id": "1234",
    "cust_id": "pqr123",
    "cust_name": "pqr",
},  <Insights> {
    "account_id": "1234",
    "actions": [
        {
            "action_type": "purchase",
            "value": "45"
        }
    ],
    "cust_id": "abc123",
    "cust_name": "abc",
 }
 ]
```

I want the data frame something like this

```
- account_id    add_to_cart purchase    cust_id cust_name
- 1234                    8        2    xyz123  xyz
- 1234                                  pqr123  pqr
- 1234                            45    abc123  abc
```

When I use the following

```
> insights_1 = [x for x in insights]

> df = pd.DataFrame(insights_1)
```

I get the following

```
- account_id                                       actions  cust_id cust_name
- 1234  [{'value': '8', 'action_type': 'add_to_cart'},{'value': '2', 'action_type': 'purchase'}]                                    xyz123  xyz
- 1234                                              NaN     pqr123  pqr
- 1234  [{'value': '45', 'action_type': 'purchase'}]        abc123  abc
```

How do I move ahead with this?

Comment: I'm sorry for asking this, but what is an `<insights>`?

Comment: That's how the output is displayed when the API is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one solution.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(insights)

parts = [pd.DataFrame({d['action_type']: d['value'] for d in x}, index=[0])
         if x == x else pd.DataFrame({'add_to_cart': [np.nan], 'purchase': [np.nan]})
         for x in df['actions']]

df = df.drop('actions', 1)\
       .join(pd.concat(parts, axis=0, ignore_index=True))

print(df)

  account_id cust_id cust_name add_to_cart purchase
0       1234  xyz123       xyz           8        2
1       1234  pqr123       pqr         NaN      NaN
2       1234  abc123       abc         NaN       45
```

**Explanation**

- Utilise `pandas` to read the outer list of dictionaries into a dataframe.
- For the inner dictionaries, use a list comprehension together with a dictionary comprehension.
- Account for `nan` values by testing for equality within the list comprehension.
- Concatenate and join the parts to the original dataframe.

**Explanation - detail**

This details the construction and use of `parts`:

1. Take each entry in `df['actions']`; each entry will be a *list
   of dictionaries*.
2. Iterate them one by one, i.e. by row, in a `for` loop.
3. The `else` part says "if it is `np.nan` [i.e. null] then return a dataframe of `nan`s". The `if` part takes the list of dictionaries and creates a mini-dataframe *for each row*.
4. We then use the next part to concatenate these mini-dictionaries, one for each row, and join them to the original dataframe.

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly fine, until I was asked to add a parameter. I have edited the original question with the details. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @raul0002, I've rolled back your question. Can you please post as a *separate* question and link to this one? Your edit isn't lost (you can still access it in the revisions). But given other people have posted answers, it's important we don't have a detached Q&A.

Comment: The link to the extension to the above question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50119490/convert-list-of-dictionaries-containing-another-list-of-dictionaries-with-multip

Answer (score 1):

I think using `apply` to your `df` will be an option. First I would replace `NaN` with empty list:

```
df['actions'][df['actions'].isnull()] = df['actions'][df['actions'].isnull()].apply(lambda x: [])
```

You create a function `add_to_cart` to read in the list of actions if the type is `add_to_cart` and use `apply` to create the column:

```
def add_to_cart(list_action):
    for action in list_action:
        # for each action, see if the key action_type has the value add_to_cart and return the value
        if action['action_type'] == 'add_to_cart':
            return action['value']
    # if no add_to_cart action, then empty
    return ''

df['add_to_cart'] = df['actions'].apply(add_to_cart)
```

Same idea for `purchase`:

```
def purchase(list_action):
    for action in list_action:
        if action['action_type'] == 'purchase':
            return action['value']
    return ''

df['purchase'] = df['actions'].apply(purchase)
```

Then you can drop the column `actions` if you want:

```
df = df.drop('actions',axis=1)
```

EDIT: define a unique function `find_action` and then `apply` with an argument, such as:

```
def find_action(list_action, action_type):
    for action in list_action:
        # for each action, see if the key action_type is the one wanted
        if action['action_type'] == action_type:
            return action['value']
    # if not the right action type found, then empty
    return ''
df['add_to_cart'] = df['actions'].apply(find_action, args=(['add_to_cart']))
df['purchase'] = df['actions'].apply(find_action, args=(['purchase']))
```