# Convert list of dictionaries containing another list of dictionaries with multiple values to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

This question is in addition to the question posted at [Convert list of dictionaries containing another list of dictionaries to dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50106611/convert-list-of-dictionaries-containing-another-list-of-dictionaries-to-datafram/50107438?noredirect=1#comment87255090_50107438)

I was asked to add a Parameter in my API call and now the output has become a bit complicated than the above one.

The output is something like this:

```
insights = [ <Insights> "account_id": "1234",
                    "actions": [{'value': '5', 'action_type': 'add_to_cart', 'view': '5'}],
                    "cust_id": "xyz123",
                    "cust_name": "xyz",
}, <Insights> {
    "account_id": "1234",
    "cust_id": "pqr123",
    "cust_name": "pqr",
},  <Insights> {
    "account_id": "1234",
    "actions": [
        {'click': '8', 'value': '110', 'action_type': 'add_to_cart', 'view': '102'}, {'value': '12', 'action_type': 'purchase', 'view': '12'}
    ],
    "cust_id": "abc123",
    "cust_name": "abc",
 }
 ]
```

Now I want the solution something like this

```
- account_id a2cart_view a2cart_click pur_view pur_click cust_id cust_name
- 1234                 5                                   xyz123 xyz
- 1234                                                     pqr123 pqr
- 1234               102           8        12             abc123 abc
```

I tried using the solution at the above link, but getting stuck when the program cannot find a particular value in one of the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by changing my answer to your previous question, you can achieve what you want. Still start by filling `nan` with empty list:

```
df['actions'][df['actions'].isnull()] = df['actions'][df['actions'].isnull()].apply(lambda x: [])
```

Then define the function `find_action` with another parameter `what`:

```
def find_action (list_action, action_type, what):
    for action in list_action:
        # for each action, see if the key action_type is the one wanted and what in the keys
        if action['action_type'] == action_type and what in action.keys():
            return action[what]
    # if not the right action type found, then empty
    return ''
```

Now, you can use `apply` with two arguments:

```
df['a2cart_view'] = df['actions'].apply(find_action, args=(['add_to_cart','view']))
df['a2cart_click'] = df['actions'].apply(find_action, args=(['add_to_cart','click']))
df['pur_view'] = df['actions'].apply(find_action, args=(['purchase','view']))
df['pur_click'] = df['actions'].apply(find_action, args=(['purchase','click']))
```

and drop the column `actions`:

```
df = df.drop('actions',axis=1)
```